# Why this constructor is not intercepted by my code?

Tags: byte-buddy

I want to write a javaagent using byte-buddy. I wan to intercept constructor of any class that is a sub class of `java.sql.Connection`.

my setup code:

```
log.info("{} profile activated", profile);
if (profile.equals("hikari")) {
    startMatcher = nameStartsWith("com.zaxxer.hikari");
    JDBCAPIInterceptor.profile = new HikariProfile();
} else if (profile.equals("dbcp1")) {
    startMatcher = nameStartsWith("org.apache.commons.dbcp");
    JDBCAPIInterceptor.profile = new DBCP1Profile();
} else if (profile.equals("dbcp2")) {
    startMatcher = nameStartsWith("org.apache.commons.dbcp2");
    JDBCAPIInterceptor.profile = new DBCP2Profile();
} else if (profile.equals("druid")) {
    startMatcher = nameStartsWith("com.alibaba.druid.pool");
} else {
    startMatcher = any();
}
new AgentBuilder.Default().type(startMatcher.and(isSubTypeOf(java.sql.Connection.class).or(isSubTypeOf(java.sql.Statement.class))))
        .transform(constructorTransformer).transform(methodsTransformer).with(listener).installOn(inst);
```

but why constructor of `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper` can't be intercepted while it's definitely a sub class of `java.sql.Connection` as it extends `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection` which implements `java.sql.Connection`?

also, my intercepting code is executed while constructor of `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection` being called.

```
public class PoolingDataSource<C extends Connection> implements DataSource, AutoCloseable {

    /**
     * PoolGuardConnectionWrapper is a Connection wrapper that makes sure a closed connection cannot be used anymore.
     *
     * @since 2.0
     */
    private class PoolGuardConnectionWrapper<D extends Connection> extends DelegatingConnection<D> {

        PoolGuardConnectionWrapper(final D delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws SQLException {
            if (getDelegateInternal() != null) {
                super.close();
                super.setDelegate(null);
            }
        }

        /**
         * @see org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection#getDelegate()
         */
        @Override
        public D getDelegate() {
            return isAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed() ? super.getDelegate() : null;
        }

        /**
         * @see org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection#getInnermostDelegate()
         */
        @Override
        public Connection getInnermostDelegate() {
            return isAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed() ? super.getInnermostDelegate() : null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isClosed() throws SQLException {
            return getDelegateInternal() == null || super.isClosed();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure how your *constructorTransformer* looks like, but is there maybe an error when doing so? Generally, this should be possible.

Comment: when testing with junit, datasource constructed before instrumention setup, what's why the  constructor of class `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper` is not intercepted.

Comment: In such a case, Byte Buddy offers redefinition. It does however limit the transformation options.